# Optimize J$ plus combine 3 <scripts> into 1

Tags: javascript, performance, optimization, code-snippets

May you please tell me how you would optimize this J$ and merge it as well. Basically, the they are duplicates of each other but just add different classes to different elements.

You can see the "drawer" on [this website](http://vondelphia.com/nexus/home.html) - look for the "*Get Your FREE...*"

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#drawer-closed").click(function(){
        $(".get-free-program .btn").addClass("expander425");
    });
});
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#drawer-closed").click(function(){
        $(".get-free-program form").addClass("showform");
    });
});
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#drawer-closed").click(function(){
        $(".get-free-program img.arrowToggler").addClass("arrow-flipper");
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#drawer-closed").click(function(){
        $(".get-free-program .btn").addClass("expander425");
          $(".get-free-program form").addClass("showform");
 $(".get-free-program img.arrowToggler").addClass("arrow-flipper");
  });
});
</script>
```

Should do

Comment: Your right, it works great! What if I wanted to add a "toggle" to this script. Like, for example remove (recently added) class on click?

Comment: change addClass to toggleClass and it should work fine

Answer (score 3):

You can use chaining. It is much faster than individual adding class.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#drawer-closed").click(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            if ($this.hasClass("toggleStart")) {
                $this.removeClass("toggleStart");
                $(".get-free-program").find(".btn").removeClass("expander425").end().find("form").removeClass("showform").end().find('img.arrowToggler').removeClass("arrow-flipper");

            } else {
                $this.addClass("toggleStart");
                $(".get-free-program").find(".btn").addClass("expander425").end().find("form").addClass("showform").end().find('img.arrowToggler').addClass("arrow-flipper");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: chaining appears to be the swift way to do things, it appears as if it doesn't add control / flexibility like @guest271314 recommended but it's easy to understand as an ingoranus..such as myself ^ _ ^

Comment: @MaggewDotCom: Yes, you are right here in that case chaining will become complicated. So here my suggestion is before adding class to specific child elements. You can just remove these classes after checking few condition. I have updated my code. Please check !

Answer (score 1):

You can store selectors, `className`s at arrays, use `$.each()` to attach event to each selector, use `index` parameter of `$.each()` to add `className` corresponding to selector index

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var selectors = [".btn", "form", "img.arrowToggler"];
    var c = ["expander425", "showform", "arrow-flipper"];
    $.each(selectors, function(index, el) {
      $("#drawer-closed").click(function() {
        $(".get-free-program " + el).addClass(c[index]);
      });
    })
});
```

Comment: I really like how I can "queue" up selectors with this code. you did a great job.